# Promela system with unranged values

Tags: queue, formal-verification, spin, promela

```
int rq_begin = 0, rq_end = 0;
int av_begin = 0, av_end = 0;

#define MAX_DUR 10
#define RQ_DUR 5

proctype Writer() {
    do
    ::  (av_end < rq_end) -> av_end++;
        if
        :: (av_end - av_begin) > MAX_DUR -> av_begin = av_end - MAX_DUR;
        :: else -> skip;
        fi
        printf("available span: [%d,%d]\n", av_begin, av_end);
    od
}

proctype Reader() {
    do
    ::  d_step {
            rq_begin++;
            rq_end = rq_begin + RQ_DUR;
        }
        printf("requested span: [%d,%d]\n", rq_begin, rq_end);
        (rq_begin >= av_begin && rq_end <= av_end);
        printf("got requested span\n");
    od
}

init {
    run Writer();
    run Reader();
}
```

This system (only an example) should model a reader/writer queue where the reader requests a certain span of frames `[rq_begin,rq_end]`, and the writer should then make at least this span available. `[av_begin,av_end]` is the span of available frames.

The 4 values are absolute frame indices, `rq_begin` gets incremented infinitley as the reader reads the next span of frames.

The system cannot be directly verified because the values are unranges (generating infinitely many states). Does Promela/Spin (or a similar software) has support to verify a system like this, and automatically transform it such that it becomes finite?

For example if all the 4 values were incremented by the same amount, the situation would still be the same. Or it could be reformulated into a model which instead has variables for the differences of these values, for example `av_end - rq_end`.

I'm using Promela/Spin to verify a more complex queuing system which uses absolute frame indices like this.

Comment: *Comment 1.* I don't really know the answer, but I do have a *question* out of curiosity. Is there any *special reason* why you don't want to *restrict your model* and *verification* up to a *finite size N*? That's what I would normally do.

Comment: *Comment 2.* I am not sure that your claim that `rq_begin` is incremented *infinitely* holds, since according to the [docs](http://spinroot.com/spin/Man/datatypes.html) `int` is *bounded* within `INT_MIN..INT_MAX`. It seems to me that at a certain point `rq_begin` will wrap around, and then both processes will be *blocked* because of the two *boolean expressions* evaluating to *false*. I don't know whether this intended or not, nor if it appears in your original model too. In either case, the state space should still be *finite*, even though *"exponentially"* large.

Comment: Otherwise, instead of *hard-coding* a smaller *range* for your variables, what you *could* is to perform a *breadth first* exploration of the *state space* rather than the default *depth first* search, by executing `spin` with the options `-bfs` or `-bfspar`.. that would give you the *certainty* that up to a certain depth level *N* *[remark: only up to such depth]*, which depends on when you stop the search tool, the property is not violated. *I don't know whether further approaches exist, so I am interested in an answer to this question as well.*

Comment: I'm now using a finite size N. The problem is that it becomes hard to know the minimal N required for complete verification in more complex models. Another solution is to atomically decrement all variables when `rq_begin` gets incremented, but it also needs to change local variables inside processes.